# Column (vertical) sum list of list

Tags: r

just like a column sum X1$value + X2$value in data frame, I would like to perform it on list of list with little R code as possible instead of using for-loop. Thanks.

Input:

```
n1 <- c(1,2,3)
n2 <- c(2,3,4)
df1 <- data.frame(n1,n2)

n1 <- c(3,2,1)
n2 <- c(5,5,6)
df2 <- data.frame(n1,n2)

mylist <- list(df1, df2)

n0 <- c(0,0,0) #init compute
compute <- data.frame(n0)

for(i in 1:length(mylist)){
    compute[,1] <- mylist[[i]]$n1 + compute[,1] 
}
```

Desired output:

```
>compute
  n0
1 4
2 4
3 4
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do this using `Reduce` and select the column you need, i.e.

```
Reduce(`+`, mylist)
#Reduce(`+`, mylist)['n1']  <-- This will extract the n1 column
```

which gives,

> ```
>   n1 n2
> 1  4  7
> 2  4  8
> 3  4 10
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Sotos's answer, but use the `reduce` function from the [purrr](/questions/tagged/purrr) package and the `select` function from the [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) package to prepare the `compute` data frame.

```
library(tidyverse)
compute <- reduce(mylist, `+`) %>% select(n0 = n1)
compute
#   n0
# 1  4
# 2  4
# 3  4
```

Answer (score 2):

Just like we would do with *dataframes*, we could use `$` if the list was named:

```
# named list
mylist <- list(df1 = df1, df2 =  df2)

# add columns
mylist$df1$n1 + mylist$df2$n1
# [1] 4 4 4
```

If the list is not named:

```
mylist[[1]][1] + mylist[[2]][1]
```

Comment: @akrun Yes, good point, but wanted to show OP that it is still possible to use `$` with lists as they are already doing with dfs. `"I am commenting on your answer only bcz you came and commented yesterday ... "` - This shouldn't be the reason to comment.

Answer (score 1):

Extract the column 'n1' with `sapply` and do `rowSums`

```
data.frame(n0 = rowSums(sapply(mylist, `[[`, 'n1')))
#  n0
#1  4
#2  4
#3  4
```

There are other options like `lapply`, `vapply` etc.  Only we need to tweak the above to convert it to `data.frame`.

```
rowSums(data.frame(lapply(mylist, `[[`, 'n1')))
```

---

Or the same in `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
mylist %>%
      map(~ .x %>%
                select(n1))  %>% 
      bind_cols %>%
      rowSums
```

Or other option is

```
mylist %>%
    map( ~ .x %>%
             select(n1)) %>%
    reduce(`+`)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
compute<-data.frame(n0=rowSums(do.call(cbind, lapply(mylist, `[[`, 1))))
compute
  n0
1  4
2  4
3  4
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `purrr:transpose`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

mylist  %>%
  purrr::transpose() %>%
  purrr::map(as.data.frame) %>%
  `[[`("n1") %>%
  rowSums %>%
  data.frame(n0 = .)

#   n0
# 1  4
# 2  4
# 3  4
```